# Linux console output gets corrupted with ASCII characters

Tags: linux, console, debian, console-application

I am implementing a software project using C++ on Debian. When I execute the stand alone binary on a debian box, program runs fine for at least 15-20 minutes but after a while the console output becomes corrupted. I see lots of ASCII characters for most of the characters, but some characters display fine, so output becomes almost unreadable. If I CTRL+C and stop the execution, whatever I type on command line is also displayed as weird ASCII characters. If I reboot the box and start over, everything works fine for another 15-20 minutes then the same thing happens. Does anybody have any idea what might be going on here? Debian box has only command line support no GUI.

Comment: try `reset` on the terminal instead of reboot

Comment: I would much prefer preventing it

Comment: Check out [this page](http://linux.about.com/od/ttl_howto/a/hwtttl17t08_2.htm) for info on getting out of the "weird" tty mode.

Comment: If you look carefully, your entire display is full of ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are printing some unwanted characters at some point. I think you may have a problem with managing memory you use for strings. Try running your program under valgrid. You can follow [this tutorial](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/). You should expect warnings about reading from uninitialized memory.

Comment: I will give it a try with valgrind, when I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using "ASCII" properly here. Considering the fact that ASCII is in range 0-127, there's not much "weird" stuff in that range. I've seen that happen before, it's usually due to escape characters interpreted as display codes. I am a bit fuzzy on this -- I haven't done console stuff in a long while. But I'm pretty sure it's related to raw output of stuff that actually out of ASCII range.

Comment: I totally agree, I will look into this issue with valgrind